# Im trying using class modelForm in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class modelBlog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ('{}.{}').format(self.id, self.title)
class comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(modelBlog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    komentar = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
```

My forms.py:

```
from .models import modelContact, comment
from django import forms


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = comment
        fields = [
            'name',
            'komentar',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'komentar': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),

        }
```

And views.py:

```
def detail(request, id):
    blog = modelBlog.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nama = request.POST['nama']
        comment = request.POST['komentar']
        new_comment = blog.comment_set.create(name=nama,komentar=comment)
        new_comment.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Komentar berhasil ditambahkan')
        return redirect('blog:detail', id)
    judul = blog.title
    context = {
        'title':judul,
        'blog':blog,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

i got error
ValueError at /blog/1/
ModelForm has no model class specified.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/1/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
ModelForm has no model class specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think, you have written `meta` in smallcase, write it in Pascal case that is `Meta` and write all your models in PascalCase such as `Comment` etc.

Comment: Write all your models also in PascalCase otherwise they'll give error later.